# OpenPyxl Excel - Function to change cell width to fit cell value?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm writing a little program to create an excel file. I've managed to change style attributes of cells, but I was wondering if there was a function or an attribute that automatically changes cells' width based on the length of the cells' values. Just like when you double click on the column to do it manually.

I found a way to change the width to a specific number, but every column's title has a different length and I would end up having a lot of blank space.

Maybe a function calle autofit or something similar?

Comment: No, there isn't. You have to the calculations yourself.

Comment: Damn, ok. Is there a way to calculate it for each column's title length?

Comment: There's the official one in the documentation. Note, that this is intended for the applications reading the worksheet. I generally use wordrap.